# Soundcloud Flash Failback - api enabled?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm using the html5 soundcloud widget on a site. I'm responding to various events using the api documented here : http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget

In IE8 the widget fails over to the flash player. The widget api script throws some errors because of the use of indexOf(). I am assuming that the script provided to interact with the widget is not intended to work when the widget has failed back to flash.

I looked into using the flash api which is documented here : http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget

I'm detecting the use of the flash player then attempting to listen to events fired on play and end. The javascript events are not firing, and my guess is because the failback embed code does not include the "enable_api=true" flashvar, is this true?

If yes, is there a way to set this flashvar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just added `enable_api` parameter for Flash fallback.
It will be hopefully deployed tomorrow.
Thanks for letting us know.